# Что означает разговорное выражение «синтаксический сахар»?

Tags: синтаксис, терминология, любой-язык

В видео-уроках встретилось выражение у автора **синтаксический сахар**, что оно означает?

Comment: я в своё время написал вопрос для викторины об этом термине. Постарался кратко и внятно сформулировать: «ЭТО дополнение синтаксиса языка программирования не добавляет новых возможностей, а только облегчает использование языка человеком.» (19 букв)

Answer (score 9):

Словосочетание "*синтаксический сахар*" используется для описания синтаксических конструкций, которые вводятся только для упрощения реализации чего-либо (сокращения объема кода, повышения читаемости и т.д.) в том или ином языке.

При этом, без синтаксического сахара вполне можно обойтись, но реализация без его использования получится более громоздкой (сложной, непонятной, ...).

Типичный пример - новый синтаксис для стрелочных функций в ES6:

```
var f = x => x*x;
```

В ES5 эту конструкцию можно записать так:

```
var f = function(x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

<sub>Для любителей JS отмечу, что стрелочные функции еще и контекст вызова "привязывают" автоматически, но в данном конкретном примере это не существенно.</sub>

Подробнее см. [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80).

Comment: "стрелочная функция" это новое название лямбда-функции? )

Comment: "_Стрелочная функция_" - это подвид анонимных (лямбда) функций в JS. В англоязычном варианте устоявшийся термин "arrow function". А называется она так по характерной стрелке `=>` в синтаксисе определения

Comment: а почему подвид, чем отличаются от прочих?

Comment: Немного другой синтаксис + автоматическая привязка `this`. Насколько мне помнится, к ним так же не применим метод `Function.prototype.bind`

Comment: Ага, примерно понял. Спасибо )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, подробнее можно посмотреть вот тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Мне всё равно придется начать с изучения основ JS ))

Answer (score 7):

Синтаксический сахар - конструкция языка, которая полностью дублирует уже имеющиеся возможности, но при этом обладает преимуществом в удобстве/краткости/похожести/стилистике.

В данном случае "тернарный оператор if" полностью совпадает с типичным if-else и присваиванием, но немного короче.

```
a = x != 0 ? a/x : 0;
```

аналогично, но короче чем

```
if(x != 0){
    a /= x;
} else {
    a = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Читаю книгу "Вы не знаете JS: This и Прототипы Объектов. Глава 4: Смешивая объекты "классов"" И наткнулся на ваш вопрос. Вот небольшой пример JS и сахара, который вы еще не раз застанете и будете возмущенны, если привыкли к ООП и классам в других языках.

> > Но значит ли это, что в JavaScript действительно есть классы? Строго и однозначно: Нет.
>
> Поскольку классы являются шаблоном проектирования, вы можете, приложив
> немало усилий (как мы увидим далее в этой главе), реализовать
> некоторое приближение для большей части классической функциональности
> класса. JS пытается удовлетворить чрезвычайно распространенное желание
> проектировать с классами, предоставляя, казалось бы, похожий на классы
> синтаксис.
>
> Хотя у нас и может быть синтаксис, похожий на классы, это больше
> похоже на то, что механика JavaScript борется против того, чтобы вы
> использовали шаблон проектирования class. Так как под капотом
> механизмы, которые вы строите, работают совсем по-другому.
> Синтаксический сахар и (очень широко используемые) JS библиотеки для
> работы с "классами" проходят долгий путь скрывая эту реальность от
> вас, но рано или поздно вы столкнетесь с тем, что классы которые у вас
> есть в других языках не похожи на фейковые "классы", которые мы
> создаем себе в JS.